# Make focusable element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way make an element focusable so it can be navigated with `TAB` key?
In the example below `<label>` element is clickable, but it can't be triggered via keyboard.

```css
*:focus
{
  background-color: pink;
  outline: 1px dotted red !important;
}

#test:checked ~ * label[for="test"]
{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="test" type="checkbox" style="display:none">
  <div class="container">
    <input>
    <label for="test">click me</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"?, your `input` is already focusable with TAB key

Comment: it is already focusable with tab as default - elaborate more please

Comment: You could add a `tabindex` to the label, but you'd still need to add the event listeners yourself with JS if you want keyboard events to be passed through to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is `tabindex=0` as an attribute to the `<label>` tag.

e.g.

```
<label for="test" tabindex="0">click me</label>
```

This will allow the browser to pick up the element as a tabbable item. This can also be applied to any HTML element, although it is not always recommended and should also be warned that if an element is tabbable, it should also have an action associated with it. Most users will instinctually press the "enter" key on a tabbable item and expect an action to occur.